# Class TDBText not found

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, classes

Bom dia, amigos. Estou tendo problemas com um programa, pois sempre que inicio uma das opções, ele me retorna um erro de "Class TDBText not found', sendo que o pacote que consta essa classe está declarado na uses do programa. Gostaria de saber o que eu poderia fazer em relação a isso? Estou usando o Delphi 6 nesse programa.

[uses declaradas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cdFd.png)

[image: erro no programa]

Comment: A partir de quando esse erro começou a acontecer? Teve alguma alteração que desencadeou o mesmo? Funciona em alguma outra tela?

Comment: O erro acontece em uma tela especifica do sistema, sempre que eu peço para abrir uma tela específica, ele gera este erro e sequer abre a tela. E não lembro de ter feito nenhuma alteração anormal no sistema para que gerasse isso.

Comment: Há algum código no *onCreate*, *onPaint* ou *onShow* do form? Se sim, qual? Há algum código no *Initialization* do form? E por útlimo, visto você estar trabalhando com componentes *Dataware*, o dataset já está aberto ao abrir o form ou é aberto após a abertura?

Comment: Bom dia, Amigo! Consegui resolver o problema, em algum momento que estava mexendo no form da tela do programa, eu adicionei um componente indefinido sem prestar atenção, isso implicava no erro acima. Após remover esse componente o programa rodou sem problemas de erro! Muito obrigado por tentar ajudar :D